# Avoid Hidden files while calculating disk usage?

Tags: disk-usage

I am using ubuntu LTSP ,
I want to find tje size of my home folder using ,
du command,
I try du -hs /home/students/cs2011/cs1105 ,
but it shows more size than what i get by taking the properties

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity you are getting is because when you right click on a folder and check its properties, it shows you much size the file/folder has occupied on disk, i.e. its disk usage and **not** because of hidden files.

However, `du` shows the file size, i.e, the number of bytes the file/folder has. This is different from the size occupied by the file/folder because of [spare blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), [internal fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29#Internal_fragmentation) and other parameter which are filesystem-dependent.

To remove this ambiguity, use du as follows:

```
du --apparent-size -hs
```

From [du's manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du):

> ```
>   --apparent-size
>           print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage;
>           although the apparent size is usually smaller, 
>           it may be larger due to holes in (`sparse') files, 
>           internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
> ```